# org-mode how to trace back invalid-duration-format

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I might be having the same problem as [Upgrading to org-mode 9.1.6 error: org-duration-to-minutes: Invalid duration format: "val"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38965/upgrading-to-org-mode-9-1-6-error-org-duration-to-minutes-invalid-duration-for) . I really am lost. I also get `Invalid duration format: "+0:30"` . And I just can't figure out which entry is causing the trouble. There is no :effort: entry in the file that is causing the trouble. If I exclude that file from my agenda files I can view an agenda (of course, with all the information missing from that one file). There is also no `+0` something that might be causing that. I do not use AM or PM. And I fear I might have to comment **all** the lines and try for each line whether it's causing that trouble. And I really would like to be able to just see my calendar for tomorrow. Is there any way to search faster than this manual search?

Comment: If you do `(setq debug-on-error t)` you will get a lisp backtrace that should provide more context on which entry is causing the issue.

Comment: `M-x org-lint` is always my first choice for data problems like this, but I don't think it's going to help in this case - you might try it anyway. My second choice would be at look at the file very carefully: are you *sure* you cannot see a `+0:30`? My third choice would be to reload Org mode uncompiled ` C-u M-x org-reload <RET>`, ([edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug) the function `org-duration-to-minutes` and try generating the agenda: ...

Comment: when the debugger stops at the function, examine the `duration` argument with `e duration RET`. If it looks OK, just continue with `c` and keep examining the variable every time it stops, until you get your "+0:30". When you do, generate a backtrace with `d` and either add it to your question if you need help or figure out how to read it and determine the suspect entry.

Comment: My third choice is @rpluim's method :-)

Comment: Thank you for all your ideas. It seemed to be solved by a simple linux system restart. So I don't know where the problem really came from.

Comment: I had same issue (i.e., org-duration-to-minutes: Invalid duration format: "+0:30" error and could not find it) It turned out that this was for the appointment that passed midnight with its duration <2021-04-19 Mon 23:00-24:30> which was originally set with 23:00+1:30. Fixing that to 23:00-24:00 solved the issue. Probably still a bug in Org mode at least for the version 9.4.4